# Javascript Date is not formatting correctly using `toLocaleString`

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, date-formatting

I am trying to format date in 'MM/dd/yyyy' (short date format) using `toLocaleString` function of javascript `Date`. But it is not giving expected result when I change my timezone. Bellow is snippet of my code

```
var d1 = new Date(1954, 0, 1); // Fri Jan 01 1954 00:00:00 GMT-0900 (AKST)
var options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit'
};
var shortDate = d1.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
console.log(shortDate);
```

Above code prints `12/31/1953` instead of expected result which is `01/01/1954`.

Observations/Steps:

- Change timezone of local machine to `Whitehorse - Canada`(`Pacific DayLight Time`).
- Run above code snippet to replicate result.
- It only gets reproduced for `year` value less than `1968` (works fine for years greater than `1968`)

For reference, uploaded recording for it (http://recordit.co/cdWMgWFLKJ)

Comment: Please elaborate on what precisely you mean by "when I change my timezone". As is, the code you gave has no time zone conversion going on at all, and will always give `01/01/1954` regardless of the computer's time zone setting.

Comment: Exactly, that is what my expectations were(No timezone used should always return me same result) which is not happening. If I keep default timezone(`GMT+0530 (IST)`) on my local machine it returns me `01/01/1954` whereas if I change it to some location nearby US timezone(e.g. `GMT-0900 (AKST)`) it is giving me `12/31/1953`. I am using crome console to test this scenario.

Comment: I think perhaps maybe you are constructing `d1` differently than you are showing here?

Comment: I have added small recording of same plz check [link](http://recordit.co/cdWMgWFLKJ)

Comment: Thanks for the recording.  I believe you have found a bug, probably with regard to how Chrome on Mac is reloading its time zone data when the os time zone changes.  It would be interesting to know if it gives the same result if you close and restart Chrome completely with the new time zone.  I'm guessing not.  Either way, you should file a bug report under the guidelines here: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines.   Also note, I could not reproduce this on Windows.

Comment: Indeed, even looks like bug in crome itself. Results are unchanged even after restarting browser. Few more finding, I can replicate it on Windows as well & on Windows it is happening for year less than `1984` & not reproducible on IE & FF. Whereas on Mac we can replicate it on FF & Safari as well. I am moving ahead to report it, Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

local date time function is a conversion from UTC to locale date time. You need to change UTC time first.

so use this.

```
var d1 = new Date(Date.UTC(1954, 0, 1)); // Fri Jan 01 1954 00:00:00 GMT-0900 (AKST)
var options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit'
};
var shortDate = d1.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
console.log(shortDate);
```

Comment: If indeed the input was meant to be interpreted as midnight UTC on this date, then sure - this would display the local time equivalent.  But such requirement is not stated in the OP.

Comment: Yes, requirement is to create & display `Date` in local timezone only. A possible solution can be to create UTC date & display it in UTC format only by setting options property `timeZone` to `UTC` explicitly. But I am trying to understand what is problem with the case where we perform all operations in local timezone only.

Comment: @Ajax The problem is when you're creating the new date it uses the current time zone. If you change the time zone, you get a DIFFERENT date.